# php mktime AMPM value wrong

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the next minute value in php by doing the following.

```
$one_minute_later = mktime(date("g"), date("i")+1, date("s"), date("n"), date("j"), date("Y"));

$send_month = date("n", $one_minute_later); // Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros

$send_day = date("j", $one_minute_later); // Day of the month without leading zeros     

$send_year = date("Y", $one_minute_later);

$send_hour = date("g", $one_minute_later); // 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros

$send_minute = date("i", $one_minute_later); // Minutes with leading zeros 00 to 59

$send_ampm = date("A", $one_minute_later);
```

However, doing so ALWAYS returns the value AM for AMPM. Any idea why? For instance, when I run this code at 6:00 PM, one minute later should return 6:01 PM. However, it's returning 6:01 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `mktime` works with 24 hours. Maybe you have noticed that it doesn't take an AM/PM parameter? That's because the hour parameter represents 24 hour time, not 12. Use `date('H')` instead of `date('g')`.

Or, simply use `time() + 60` for this whole operation.

Comment: You're right! I totally missed that. Thanks for the quick answer Deceze. I really appreciate it.